# What would the EU do if an EU member declared war on another EU member?

Tags: european-union, international-law, international, europe

What would the EU do if an EU member declared war on another EU member? I am wondering what would happen if a country like France attacked a country like Cyprus, what would the EU do in that situation? Is there a sort of mechanism in place that would guide the EU in its decision?

Comment: Probably nobody knows. In love and war everything is possible.

Comment: Aren't they all NATO members as well? That would also be a factor.

Comment: That question has -- until that became non-discussable for other reasons -- for a long, long time been the strongest argument against Turkey's efforts to join the EU. Seeing how they occupy an EU member state (the one mentioned in the question, incidentially) since 45 or so years.

Comment: @vsz All EU members are not NATO members (for example Finland is not, although the debate about joining NATO has been going on for a long time)

Comment: @vsz Not all of them are. In particular, countries pursuing a policy of neutrality including Ireland, Sweden, Finland, Austria did not join NATO (and generally avoid military alliances).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the provisions in the [Treaty on European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_European_Union), the EU itself wouldn't be able to do much directly, however it could delegate a conflict resolution task to some number of member states. Further, all EU members would be obligated to provide aid to the attacked member state.

[Title V, Chapter 2, Section 2](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Consolidated_version_of_the_Treaty_on_European_Union/Title_V:_General_Provisions_on_the_Union%27s_External_Action_Service_and_Specific_Provisions_on_the_Common_Foreign_and_Security_Policy#SECTION_2:_PROVISIONS_ON_THE_COMMON_SECURITY_AND_DEFENCE_POLICY) of the Treaty on European Union states the following:

> 1. The common security and defence policy shall be an integral part of the common foreign and security policy. It shall provide the Union with an operational capacity drawing on civilian and military assets. **The Union may use them on missions outside the Union for peace-keeping, conflict prevention and strengthening international security** in accordance with the principles of the United Nations Charter. The performance of these tasks shall be undertaken using capabilities provided by the Member States.
>
> ...
>
> 5. The Council may entrust the execution of a task, within the Union framework, to a group of Member States **in order to protect the Union's values and serve its interests**. The execution of such a task shall be governed by Article 44.
>
> ...
>
> 7. **If a Member State is the victim of armed aggression on its territory, the other Member States shall have towards it an obligation of aid and assistance by all the means in their power**, in accordance with Article 51 of the United Nations Charter. This shall not prejudice the specific character of the security and defence policy of certain Member States.

Comment: `Further, all EU members would be obligated to provide aid to the attacked member state` - i guess that technically includes the aggressor?

Comment: @hanshenrik - One would imagine their "aid" would come in the form of efforts to liberate the attacked state from its politicians who put it in the position to get attacked by the aggresssor.

Comment: @hanshenrik "say no more fam, I'm already at the location of the problem."

Answer (score 10):

I would expect the EU to work very hard to try to mediate and resolve any dispute between members *long* before it got to the point where one member was to declare war on another.

If a large and influential nation like France was to attack a smaller nation like Cyprus 'out of the blue', it would probably be an existential threat to the EU itself, as it would be a huge blow to the spirit of cooperation and trust that the EU is founded on. Other members would be forced to either take sides; reprimand or punish France somehow (which would be difficult and cause a lot of internal tension); or otherwise turn a blind eye as France 'has a go' at Cyprus. None of those options would be very appealing or positive for EU cohesion.

Answer (score 0):

According to the treaties, they would have to defend both members. So they would fight for one member on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, and for the other member on Tuesday, Thursday, and Saturday. Sunday could be used to plan the schedule for the next week.

---

Seriously, two EU members fighting a war is quite incomprehensible for logistical reasons, as well as political ones. The EU members have already integrated their armed forces to a degree that only small expeditionary detachments could fight independently. Anything larger than that would run into the problems that *some* specialized capability is only provided by a few member nations.

---

**Follow-Up**:
NATO has nine rapid deployable corps headquarters in Europe: ARRC, EUROCORPS, Northeast, Italy, Turkey, German-Netherlands, Spain, France, Greece. Turkey isn't EU, and the EU has some members who are not NATO, but the big ones are.

Not sure about the Spain and France (and Turkey) headquarters, but the rest are multinational.

France and the UK have their own AWACS squadron, the rest of the EU either participates in the [NATO pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_E-3_Sentry#Operators) or runs much smaller aircraft like the Embraer [R-99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_R-99), [Gulfstream 550](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulfstream_G550#Variants), or [Saab 340](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saab_340_AEW%26C).

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer is not really helpful and I wonder if the second paragraph is not overestimating the level of integration of the national armies within the EU. I think it's more a vertical integration than a horizontal one.

Comment: @Trilarion, quite a lot of EM members are *also* NATO members and the smaller NATO members are quite integrated. The joint AWACS fleet is but one example.

Comment: @Trilarion I think the first paragraph is extremely helpful. Cutting out the humor is not helpful.

Comment: The second paragraph is plain wrong.

Comment: @AlanDev, have you counted the corps headquarters in Europe? And how many of them are strictly national affairs, and how many are multinational?

Comment: The second paragraph is at least plainly wrong for my EU country, maybe you need to clarify which countries you you have experience with.

Comment: 2nd paragraph: Yugoslavia. It was even more integrated, but it didn't seem to help to prevent bloody wars.

Comment: @ZizyArcher, that was a civil war with militias on the ground.

Comment: (-1) You obviously have no idea of what NATO entails and how any of this works. There is a grain of truth in that many EU nations could not conduct serious military operations on their own but that's not because EU armies are integrated or because they participate in NATO command structures, it's because the countries are small or have very limited capacities to begin with (and that includes Germany). Meanwhile, countries that do have these capabilities (France, UK...) certainly do not depend on NATO to the extent you suggest.

Comment: @Relaxed, the last **independent** UK division-sized operation I can think of would be the Falklands war. For a corps-sized operation, I'm not quite sure, perhaps the Malayan Emergency? The recent ones, *Telic*, *Granby*, *Herrick*, were all multinational. (PS -- sorry about the slow reply. I meant to google the French, but I didn't find enough time.)

Comment: @o.m. Yes, it's the same for the French, you would have to look even further in the past to find a division-sized operation, so what? That's not the point...

Comment: @Relaxed, so you are confident that the UK and France **could** mount independent larger-than-brigade operations, despite the fact that they haven't done so in a generation? I would expect that any attempt would be a shambles.

Comment: @o.m. I wouldn't expect it to be easy, no, but I never said that and it's a completely different discussion. Meanwhile, there is much that is still plainly incorrect in your answer. For starters, a brigade is not a “small expeditionary detachment” (a tenth of the French Army is currently deployed in the Sahel region). Importantly, HG RRC-FR staff is 85% French as is the equipment. The level of cooperation in NATO does not amount to an “integration“ of armed forces. Even the Franco-German brigade's organisation is such that its components could (and recently did) deploy independently.

Comment: France also has two division-level headquarters. I would not expect France to fare especially well in any high-intensity warfare situation (and neither would the US Army, incidentally) but they are not integrated in any way. A war against a neighbour is not something the French military is seriously preparing for but it wouldn't necessarily require a large *deployable* headquarters either. It would have more difficulties deploying actual troops so why even bring up NATO headquarters? You just made that up before reframing the discussion.

Comment: @Relaxed, the OP asked if two EU members could go to war with each other. The EU and the European NATO members are **not** the same but all significant ones are members of both -- I think we can ignore non-NATO states unless Sweden is going to invade Austria. So I'm not re-framing the debate, I'm paring it down to essentials by concentrating on both-EU-and-NATO countries.

Comment: @o.m. Again, not the point, whatever limitations there are, they do not result from a (non-existent) “integration”. And the comparison someone else made about the Yugoslavian wars is also very relevant. If things are so bad that European countries end up fighting a war, they would make do. European armies would perhaps not be the most effective from day one but the notion that they are integrated to the point where no nation has an independent staff is just inaccurate.

Comment: To see the distinction and how you reframed the question away from the points you made in your answer, ask yourself this: Would you be confident that Switzerland could mount independent larger-than-brigade operations? They certainly haven't done anything like that in quite some time. They have very little recent experience with actual fighting or foreign deployment at any scale... And they have a large military with no integration to any foreign force. Yet it's difficult to imagine them accepting a foreign invasion without any resistance!

Comment: @Relaxed, Switzerland has very consciously *not* integrated their forces with their neighbours. Most NATO members have. I have modest faith in their ability to execute, say, *Eagle Guardian*, but not in the ability of any one national HQ to come up with such a complex operation without the multinational headquarters.

Comment: @o.m. Yes, that's precisely why I brought it up. So which is it? Can it conduct division-level operations, yes or no? If no, why do you continue hyping up this imaginary “integration” as the main impediment to warfare between EU nations? If yes, why dismiss French and British capacities because they have not actually done it recently when Switzerland hasn't conducted *any* fighting in living memory? That's obviously true but in no way supports what you wrote in your answer (and still haven't edited despite trying to reframe the argument multiple times in comments).

Comment: @Relaxed, would you be satisfied if I say that France and the UK are the EU members **most** capable of going to war against each other? Five years ago I would have said that is an absurd fantasy, but who knows what will happen when Downing Street blames Brussels for the consequences of Brexit? On the other hand, the DoD only plans to put a brigade-sized force on standby to support Yellowhammer, with a couple of years preparation ...

Comment: @o.m. I could agree with a lot of what you wrote in comments, I think I already suggested as much. My problem is that you keep switching subjects and still haven't edited out demonstrably false considerations regarding the level of integration between European armies or how NATO-certified headquarters work. Until you do my downvote stands.

Comment: @Relaxed, take a look at the Netherlands Air Force and count the EW aircraft. On the other hand, the German naval infantry has to borrow the Karel Doorman from the Dutch. Consider the lack of tankers in the Royal Norwegian Air Force. Or in the Hellenic Air Force. But the Greek have more MBTs than the Germans. Spain has no attack helicopters. The list goes on.

Comment: @o.m. Reframing the discussion again but we discussed that earlier: Yes, some armies, especially from small countries have limited capacities. Still doesn't amount to a high level of integration or the impossiblity of a war, nobody is saying they would take on the US military on US soil! It's also not clear that attack helicopters or tanker aircraft would be terribly useful in the scenario mentioned by the OP (case in point: almost all recent conflicts).

Comment: And if there is one military that has deliberately sought integration with a foreign country, it's the Dutch military... but with the US, not some imaginary European military.  The most important fact however is that the Netherlands has 17M people and only spends 1.3% of its GDP on defense. That would be a more salient point to put in your answer than uninformed speculation regarding NATO headquarters.

Comment: In fact, you seemed to miss that but even France is severely limited when it comes to tanker aircraft (or airlift capacities in general). The air force boasted about the strike in [Syria last year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_missile_strikes_against_Syria) as one of the most complex operations they ever conducted but firing a handful of cruise missiles required half of the French capacity in that respect. Your comment suggest you have never set foot in a headquarters and googling random facts as you go. It still doesn't support your contention and is completely beside the point.

Comment: @Relaxed, actually I use google to check if the things I thought I remember are still current before I post.

Comment: @Relaxed, and you're right that I'm no soldier, but I've listened to lectures by people who were in security politics. Usually I didn't take notes, however. Now I'm trying to apply that to the question by the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97633/discussion-between-relaxed-and-o-m).